# Will iterating over Linq Lookup make a db query for each iteration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im using Entity Framework, and lets say I have some class stored in a DB:

```
class A
{
  public int Foo { get; set; }
  public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I start iterating over the result of `ToLookup` like this:

```
var data = db.Data.ToLookup(x => x.Foo);
foreach (var group in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        // use item... Console.WriteLine("\t" + item.Bar);
    }
}
```

Will this code generate only one query?

Will each iteration make a query to the DB? Or is the result of ToLookup materialized so its like iterating over some in-memory IEnumerable?

Comment: It is the latter, calling `ToLookup` retrieves the data from the store and your loop iterates over an in memory collection.

Comment: is `var data` of type `IQueryable`?

Comment: `ToLookup` is the materialized version of `GroupBy`. Similar to `ToList`, `ToDictionary` etc., it will execute the query only once and immediately.

Comment: `ToLookup` will do the query, but even if you did `foreach(var x in db.Data)` that would still only be one query to the DB and it would iterate over the results.

Comment: Will only one query be generated in the example?

Comment: [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `IEnumerable<T>`, which means it will create a single query to db and read all data to[`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) collection in memory. Then you will iterate through that collection.

Comment: If your entities have any Lazy Loading properties, that could trigger one DB call per row returned by the initial query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ToLookup(this IQueryable, ...). There is however, an [Enumerable.ToLookup(this IEnumerable, ...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073(v=vs.110).aspx)

This function takes an IEnumerable as input. Every LINQ function that uses deferred execution has a remark about this in its description.

Apparently ToLookup does not use deferred execution, so as soon as you call it, it takes the input parameter and enumerates over all elements.

This behaviour is comparable as ToList(): the query will be done only once, all enumerated data will be brought to local memory in one query before it is used to created the lookup table.

Comment: This is correct. Verified behaviour by checking source.

Comment: In LINQ `To` prefix means that the method returns "materialized" result (`ToLookup()`, `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, ...).